# Should you click all at once or one at a time

Tags: jquery

I have a button setup to click on inputs on a page , but when i click it , the site hangs for awhile. I'm wondering if there is a way to have the function click one at a time before moving to the next one , that may possibly not bog down the page when clicked ? Or a better method ?

```
function clearInput() {
     $('input').click();
}
```

Comment: why click the input?

Comment: You can use a timeout loop and click them one by one, sure.

Comment: i have to click them as another function is triggered onclick event of the input

Comment: Why not trigger those functions directly then?

Comment: have to do it this way , no other choice , existing code , need to add a button to click all inputs

Comment: You speak telegraphic style... Still. Your objective is weird. No one would use events to trigger existing code like this. It's like calling a car crash with fire to kill an ant on the street.

Comment: Tell more about your main objective... There is **certainly** a better way to do it.

Comment: didnt author the website , can't edit existing functions , all i asked was is there a better method of triggering a click event for multiple items that won't lag the site when clicked

Comment: If you can add those two line which make the site lag... You can call the existing functions too... Without using events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Debug the freeze issue, do you have event bind to each input? might be jQuery click all of them at the same time triggered too many events, try to put a breakpoint or console.log on input events, see how many are triggered etc.

To unbind all event bind to input try this one, it also set all input to null:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   _this.off();
   _this.click();
   _this.val(null); 
}, interval)
```

For your question, this is a solution to click each input with delay.

Use jquery `each()` on input, for each iteration creat a setTimeout with increase delay, I used 500ms for example, you can change it to 10ms or whatever.

```js
function clearInput() {
  var interval = 500;
  $('input').each(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      _this.click(); //this is the function you need to call
      console.log(_this.val()); //for example only, remove later
      _this.val(null); //for example only, remove later
    }, interval)
    interval += 500;
  });
}
clearInput();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1" />
<input value="2" />
<input value="3" />
<input value="4" />
<input value="5" />
```

Comment: This answers the OP question... But maybe not his problem. anyway +1